# Matplotlib Weird Graphing with Custom Colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am running into a weird issue using matplotlib to plot a function with a custom color. There is a weird red graph at the bottom of my image. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def graph(formulas, x1, x2):

    x = np.linspace(x1, x2, 400)
    for i, formula in enumerate(formulas):
        print i
        y = formula(x)
        plt.plot(x, y,(1.0, 0.25, 0.25))
    plt.show()

def parabola(a):
    return (lambda x: a * x**2)

graph((parabola(1.0),), -5, 5)
```

Here is the matplotlib custom color documentation: https://matplotlib.org/users/colors.html

Here is the generated graph:
[image]

I have no idea what's gone wrong. The graphing works perfectly when I use `'r'` for my color.

EDIT: I just ended up using the default colors. But if anyone can explain what's going on I'd still be very interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the 'multi-syntax' of the `plot` command. One of the possible ways to pass arguments to the plot command is this (straight from the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# evenly sampled time at 200ms intervals
t = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)

# red dashes, blue squares and green triangles
plt.plot(t, t, 'r--', t, t**2, 'bs', t, t**3, 'g^')
plt.show()
```

The command plots three curves, with the respective first and second arguments (for each curve) being the `x` and `y` coordinates and the respective third argument being the line color and style. You can also leave out the line style argument,

```
plt.plot(t, t, t, t**2, t, t**3)
```

in which case matplotlib uses default colors. In your case, the third argument, which you intended to be a color, was interpreted as the coordinates for a second curve. As there is only one iterable, it is interpreted as the `y` values of the curve and the x values are 'auto-filled' as `(0,1,2)`. To get the desired behaviour in your example, add the keyword `color` explicitly:

```
plt.plot(x, y, color=(1.0, 0.25, 0.25))
```

then the result looks as expected:

[image: result of the code posted by the OP with the plot command corrected as indicated above]